# uWSGI request timeout in Python

Tags: python, uwsgi

Trying to set the timeout for requests in uWSGI, I'm not sure of the correct setting.  There seem to be multiple timeout options (socket, interface, etc.) and it's not readily evident which setting to configure or where to set it.

The behavior I'm looking for is to extend the time a request to the resource layer of a REST application can take.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You're propably looking for the **harakiri** parameter - if request takes longer than specified harakiri time (in seconds), the request will be dropped and the corresponding worker recycled.

For standalone uwsgi (ini config):

```
[uwsgi]
http = 0.0.0.0:80
harakiri = 30
...
```

If you have nginx proxy before uwsgi you have to increase timeout as well:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_uwsgi_upstream;
    proxy_read_timeout 30s;
    proxy_send_timeout 30s;
  }
```

If you want (for some strange reason) higher timeout than 60s, you might consider communication over `uwsgi` protocol. Configuration is quite similar nginx site:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_read_timeout 120s;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 120s;
    uwsgi_pass  my_upstream;
    include     uwsgi_params;
}
```

uwsgi:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:80
protocol = uwsgi
harakiri = 120
...
```

Comment: I used the uwsgi protocol option and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Some queries or operations can easily take longer than 60s. Why would it be considered strange?

Comment: Because most users won't want to wait >60 seconds. And don't try to explain why you don't have a choice, I know.

Comment: I get error `NameError: name 'uwsgi' is not defined`

Comment: turns out I was adding that to a file for systemd config, not the .ini for flask

Comment: Super! I changed `uwsgi_read_timeout` and `uwsgi_send_timeout`. And it works for me!

Answer (score 24):

Setting `http-timeout` worked for me. I have `http = :8080`, so I assume if you use file system socket, you have to use `socket-timeout`.

Comment: I was able to extend the timeout by only using the `http-timeout` parameter in the uwsgi config. I didn't need `--harakiri`.

(and I also needed to set `proxy_read_timeout` and `proxy_send_timeout` in the nginx config as @Tombart said above)

Comment: will there be any issues if I used both ? I'm running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67407446/oserror-write-error-python-flask-sigpipe-writing-to-a-closed-pipe-socket-fd

Comment: In my case running `uwsgi` directly it was also the `--http-timeout` parameter.

Answer (score -2):

it worked for me by comment
`#master = true`
and put this,
`lazy-apps = true`

in uwsgi.ini file