# sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream nginx 502

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am running Django, uwsgi, ngix server. 
My server works fine for GET, POST requests of smaller size. But when POSTing requests of large size, nginx returns 502:
nginx error.log is:

```
2016/03/01 13:52:19 [error] 29837#0: *1482 sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream, client: 175.110.112.36, server: server-ip, request: "POST /me/amptemp/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "servername"
```

So, in order to find where the real problem is, I ran uwsgi on a different port and checked if any error occurs with the same request. But the request was successful. So, the problem is with nginx or unix socket configuration.
Ngin-x configuration:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
     server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock; # for a file socket
#   server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
# the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
# the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 52.25.29.179; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        charset     utf-8;

# max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /home/usman/Projects/trequant/trequant-python/trequant/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        }

    location /static {
        alias /home/usman/Projects/trequant/trequant-python/trequant/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {

########    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
########    proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
########    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
########    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 600s;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

So, any idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the file you are uploading is below 75MB and time taken in request is below 600 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I am uploading 3MB and yes, it's less than 600 seconds. In fact, the nginx responds within 30 seconds with 502 error.

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly setting `post-buffering = 8192` in your uwsgi.ini file will fix this. I got this answer from a 2.5-yr-old answer [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wsgi.uwsgi.general/6078) and it implies this fix is not the root cause.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another fix is to use a [TCP socket instead of a unix socket in your conf files](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html):

1. In uwsgi.ini, use something like `socket = 127.0.0.1:8000` in the `[uwsgi]` section instead of:

   `socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
   chown-socket = nginx:nginx
   chmod-socket = 664`
2. In your nginx.conf file (btw in Ubuntu, I'm referring to /etc/nginx/**conf.d**/nginx.conf, NOT the one simply in `/etc/nginx/`) use `uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;` instead of `include uwsgi_params;`

I've posted this as a separate answer because either answer may work, and I'm interested to see which answer helps others the most.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this seemed to be for requests that would have given a 308 redirect. I think my Node backend was sending response before postdata was fully received. Updating the client to hit new endpoint (no redirect) may permanently fix my case. Seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Set higher body buffer size `client_body_buffer_size 1M;` This will fix.

**References:**

1. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size
2. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/